# Angular2+ Top Level Navigation Containing Parents and Children - activated route error

Tags: angular, angular-routing

[Main Navigation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnvj4.png)

I have a menu (main navigation image) and due to different page layouts (all 'site' are full width) links have different parents:

1. Home - /home
2. Attractions - /site/attraction
3. Animals - /site/animals
4. Track Orders - /order/order-tracking
5. Upload Orders - /site/upload-order
6. Saved Baskets - /basket/stored-basket
7. Downloads 2017 - /site/downloads
8. About Us - /site/about-us
9. Contact - /site/contact

The routes work if going from a 'site' to 'order' parent view but error when I go 'site' to 'site' which is expected as site is activated thus not happy.

I have read up about parents and children and creating a routing and module per feature and I separated all 'site' routes into their own section, I got the same error though of 'Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet'

I will try this process again separating into separate routing module in case I made a mistake when setting it up, however, I wanted to check:

If I am using 'parent/child' correctly i.e. mixing parent and child links in the main navigation due to the fact layout is different, Site is a 'Page'? I cant find any other navigation examples doing this.

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

site.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
   <div class="container main-content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
           <router-outlet name="tertiary"></router-outlet>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

app.routes.ts  (as one route per project)

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        outlet: 'primary',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        outlet: 'primary',
        component: RegisterComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'primary',
        component: CatalogueComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'sidebar',
        component: CatalogueNavComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'products',
        outlet: 'primary',
        component: ProductsListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'products/category/:cat',
        outlet: 'primary',
        component: ProductsListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'products/detail/:code',
        outlet: 'primary',
        component: ProductdetailComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'products/search/:variables',
        outlet: 'primary',
        component: SearchProductsComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'basket',
    component: BasketComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'basket-detail',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'primary',
            component: BasketdetailComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: BasketTotalComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'checkout',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'primary',
            component: CheckoutComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: AddressComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'stored-basket',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'primary',
            component: StoredBasketComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: SearchBasketTemplatesComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'stored-basket-detail/:basketId',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'primary',
            component: StoredBasketDetailComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: StoredBasketDetailSummaryComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'your-account',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'primary',
            component: YourAccountComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: AddressComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'order',
    component: BasketComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'order-tracking',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'primary',
            component: OrderTrackingComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: SearchOrderTrackingComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'order-tracking-detail/:orderNo',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'primary',
            component: OrderTrackingDetailComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: OrderTrackingDetailAddressComponent,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'site',
    component: SiteComponent,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'contact',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: ContactComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'upload-order',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: UploadOrderComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'about-us',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: AboutComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'attraction',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: AttractionComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'animals',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: AnimalsComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'downloads',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: DownloadsComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'order-tracking-pdf/:orderNo',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: OrderTrackingPdfComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'order-confirmation/:orderNo',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: OrderConfirmationComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'account-summary-pdf',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          outlet: 'tertiary',
          component: AccountSummaryPdfComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'home'
  }
];


export const RoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {

});
```

Comment: can you post your route definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate the issue. It looks like angular requires you to have a primary router-outlet before you can have auxiliary router-outlets. I would remove the router-outlet name from your site.component.html

```
// site.component.html
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="container main-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and change the site route definitions to use `outlet: 'primary'`

Comment: @playboxdesign you could also add a dummy `<router-outlet><router-outlet>` next to your tertiary auxiliary router-outlet that would essentially not get used, but I'd just use the primary for cleanliness.